# Move UIView with animation and it rolls back by itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, storyboard

I have a UIView drawn in Storyboard which holds some buttons and which is called viewHolder.

I get a higher position `rectForAnimationBefore`

and a lower position `rectForAnimationAfter`

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:nil completion:^(BOOL finish){
                             [self.viewHolder setFrame:rectForAnimationAfter];
                         }];
```

when this is excuted,the `viewHolder` do move down.After a second,it comes up as nothing was done.

I want to moveDown,but don't want moveUp Automatically.

Because autolayout in Storyboard?
By the way ,how to move it smoothly?

Thank you guys.

UPDATE:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             [self.viewHolder setFrame:rectForAnimationAfter];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finish){

                         }];
```

when I change code like this ,I can't move it down .

**Here is my solution**

unlock the autolayout!!!

Comment: If you're using auto layout, you shouldn't be setting any frames, you should be adjusting constraints.

Comment: I cannot find the autolayout setting ):

Comment: It's in the File Inspector, in the "Interface Builder Document" section (it's a check box).

Comment: Thank you a lot.When I unlock the autolayout,everything is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing your animation block is nil. Here you should move your view down. At completion you are setting back you view without using any animation. For smoothness you need to move back your view animatedly.

Comment: I think the animation block is nil which means do not animate.And in the completion block ,I move it down.Am I wrong?

Comment: your code will move down your view without animation and after 1.0 sec of animation duration. 
Because you are not doing anything in the portion which is responsible of moving view animatedly(animation block)

Comment: So if you just want to move down your view do it in animation block.

Comment: I have change my code and add some code in the animation block .But nothing happened.

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: YES it is autolayout.Could you tell me why it will get back with autolayout?

Comment: If you will uncheck auto layout you will see you animation working correctly.

Comment: With autolayout we need to send constraints accordingly here is a guide which helps out how to use autolayout. [UsingAutoLayOut](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)